# React-Router 4 not handling direct links or refreshed pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

This issue has come up before, but the existing answers still aren't working for me. My app uses React-Router 4, with Node/Express on the back end.

I have read [Tyler McGinnis's explanation](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/). I am using Browser Router and what McGinnis calls the "Catch-all" solution. My routes look like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public')));

app.post('/auth/signin', signin);

// more Auth and CRUD routes

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
});
```

When I manually enter or refresh routes like `http://localhost:8357/admin`, this solution works fine. However, when I try that with longer routes like `http://localhost:8357/admin/create`, the app crashes. As far as I can tell, the browser loads `index.html` but then looks for bundle in `http://localhost:8357/admin/bundle`.

**Edit:** I sorta fixed this problem by hardcoding the css and bundle links in index.html, ie replacing `<script type="text/javascript" src='bundle/bundle.js'></script>` with `<script type="text/javascript" src='http://localhost:8357/bundle/bundle.js'></script>`. When I deploy I'll have to change those links. Not an elegant solution, but it works. Is  there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't believe this has anything to do with React Router.

If you want it use a path that's relative to the root of your directory, you need to make sure you have a forward slash at the beginning.

For example: instead of using `bundle/bundle.js`, you'll want to make sure you use `/bundle/bundle.js`.

Hope that works for you!